# Case Insensitive Matching in JSR-303 Bean Validation and Primefaces CSV

Tags: java, regex, primefaces, bean-validation

I am using Bean Validation and i want to allow case insensitive input.
'tas123' and 'TAS123' should be valid inputs. Lowercase is working but uppercase like 'TAS123' fails.

```
  @Pattern(regexp = "^$|^tas.*$", message = "Task ID must start with TAS", 
  flags = {Pattern.Flag.CASE_INSENSITIVE, Pattern.Flag.UNICODE_CASE})
  private String taskId;
```

I am using this in Primefaces Client Side Validation. Is there something wrong in the pattern or does primefaces not support CASE_INSENSITIVE flag on client side?

**UPDATE:**
I have tried to disable client validation with `validateClient="false"` but the validation still fails on server side.

**UDATE-2:**
Using `regexp = "(?i)^$|^tas.*$"` works in Primefaces only with `validateClient='false'`. Enabling client validation leads to an error message displayed to the user: 'undefined'. No javascript errors are displayed in the firebug console.

Comment: And if you use method like .toLowerCase() ?Like that after your input all will be in lower case.

Comment: @LandelinDelcoucq this will put noise in the code, validations are made for this purposes

Comment: can you try :- `"(?i)^$|^tas.*$"`

Comment: @rock321987 This works with disabled client side validation. But it breaks the client side validation with the error-message 'undefined'. There are no javascript errors displayed in the firebug console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a brute-force solution. Really ugly though:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^$|^[Tt][Aa][Ss].*$", message = "Task ID must start with TAS",
```

Comment: This seems to be the only way in Primefaces CSV.